# Method to rename the existing BGP peer group

Tags: bgp, cisco-asr, cisco-ios-xr, peering, asr

In Cisco ASR router, do we have any method to rename the existing peer group without removing and recreating it?

Comment: Update the startup config and reload?  Also what kind of ASR?  Guessing 9k since you say XR?

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Create the new neighbor peer group with all desired configuration.

Remove the existing neighbor from the old peer group.

Add the neighbor to the new peer group.

Remove the old peer group once everything is working.

Neighbor relationship will go down when the peer group is changed.

In other words, no, you cannot rename a peer group without just creating a new one and assigning that peer group to the neighbor which means removing the old peer group configuration from that neighbor before assigning a new one.

I would assume it is this way because Cisco has not had enough requests (or never had a request) to be able to rename a peer group while in use. The name is significant but cosmetic. You can't change it but it also doesn't really mean anything important by its own content. It's a variable used to define a configuration template. Even if they did develop a command to rename it, I would expect it to result in a brief neighbor relationship interruption anyway since it would probably just do the same thing behind the scenes (remove the old configuration association and add the same thing with a new name).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete script that combines the steps mentioned earlier to rename an existing BGP peer group in a Cisco ASR router:

```
configure terminal
router bgp <AS number>
no neighbor <peer-group-name> peer-group
neighbor <new-peer-group-name> peer-group
neighbor <BGP-neighbor> peer-group <new-peer-group-name>
end
```

Please replace  with your actual autonomous system number,  with the name of the existing peer group you want to rename,  with the desired name for the new peer group, and  with the IP address or neighbor identifier of the BGP neighbor that was previously associated with the old peer group.